# how to convert image to byte array in java?(With out using buffered image)

Tags: java, image, byte, arrays

Hi could anyone please explain me how to convert the image data to byte array in java I am trying like this.I do not need to use buffered image here.

```
File file = new File("D:/img.jpg");
        FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        imageInFile.read(imageData);
```

Comment: If you want the image decoded so you can access the pixel data, it's easier to go via a `BufferedImage`

Comment: could you please tell me, what byte[] is?   is it the bytes read from your image (just as like if you want to read byte from any orinary file)?     or do you want to get the byte from each pixel?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your image data using FileInputStream also.

```
File file = new File("D:\\img.jpg");

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
 //Now try to create FileInputStream which obtains input bytes from a file. 
 //FileInputStream is meant for reading streams of raw bytes,in this case its image data. 
 //For reading streams of characters, consider using FileReader.

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        try {
            for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
                //Now Write to this byte array output stream
                bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); 
                System.out.println("read " + readNum + " bytes,");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConvertImage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Whats the use of converting the image directly like above and by converting to buffered image to byte array.

Answer (score 0):

or you could use:

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("D:/img.jpg");
byte[] imageBytes = getImageBytes(image);


private byte[] getImageBytes(Image image) throws IOException {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", baos);
        baos.flush();
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```